# How can I cloneNode() and transform these CSS arcs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, clonenode

I'm using css to make a "pie wedge" by making a circle, clipping half of it out, and then transform-rotating another clipping rectangle so that only a 25-degree arc is showing.  This works fine; an example with six such pie wedges explicitly defined is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1a2ufa5e/1/).

What I'd like to do, however, is just define one pie wedge and then use cloneNode to make the rest via javascript, like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById('slice1');
    var child = el.cloneNode(true);
    child.id = 'newslice'+i;
    child.style.transform = "transform:rotate("+(30+i*60)+"deg)";
    el.parentNode.appendChild(child);
}
```

Example of this (non-working) code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgcgz1Lq/1/).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrongly thinking that cloneNode() would clone styles.  A working solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3h8afocs/) and looks like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById('slice1');
    var child = el.cloneNode(true);
    child.id = 'newslice'+i;
        // set the style classes for the cloned element
    child.className = " hold";
    child.children[0].className = " pie";
        // apply its transforms
    child.style.transform = "rotate("+(30+i*60)+"deg)";
    child.children[0].style.transform = "rotate(25deg)";
    el.parentNode.appendChild(child);
}
```